# Android 4.0 is not giving option to choose app for opening a file?

Tags: android, file, sd-card

I am working in a project where I need to display list of all files present in SD card in a listview and on click of list view item give user option to choose app for opening that file. Below is the code which I am using. It is working fine in Android 2.3.3. But Android 4.0 and above it opens all files in gallery photo viewer. Please advise.

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Uri path = Uri.parse("file://" + arrayListAllFilespath.get(arg2));
        //arrayListAllFilespath.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(path, "*/*");
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"dialog title"))` to launch the chooser.

Answer (score -1):

this may be you don't install more than one application to open an image.Suppose if there are more than one application to open an image then it ask to choose an application but if there is only one application install for opening an image then it use it as a default and never ask you or if you have installed more than one application then you might set gallery to open as a default